# Как вычислить частное факториалов?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Нужно написать программу, вычисляющую N!/(N-3)! без использования функций.

Удалось написать только сие:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    long double fact, fact1;
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    for (int i = N - 1; i > 0; i--)
        fact = fact * i;
    for (int i1 = N - 4; i1 > 0; i1--)
        fact1 = fact1 * i1;
    cout << fact / fact1 << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Но программа выдаёт некорректный результат. Помогите исправить.

Comment: Ужас. N!/(N-3)! равно N * (N-1) * (N-2). Кажется.

А вообще, @shtelcner, программисты -- они по жизни тупые.

Comment: Слово "кажется" употреблено вами очень к месту, любезнейший.

Comment: 2 @shtelcner: @alexlz прав. а вообще уметь программировать и уметь писать код это разные вещи. программист должен уметь анализировать задачу, подобрать оптимальный алгоритм. предположим что вы плохо знаете математику (т.е сократить формулу не судьба) но закодить подсчет факториала можно было бы в одном цикле

Comment: Вдогонку. Они могут признать реальными случаями N=0 (никто не пришёл) и N=1 (одна команда пришла и победила)

Answer (score 9):

В комментарий не влезает, увы.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "Господин, соблаговолите назвать число N, чтобы сия прогаммa вычислила N!/(N-3)! >";
    cin >> n;
    if (n < 3)
        cout << "Господин, нижайше умоляю Вас прочитать описание факториала в учебнике,\n"
                "ибо я не могу вычислить факториал отрицательного числа, "
                "и это причиняет мне невыносимые страдания!" << endl;
    else 
        cout << n << "!, делённое на " << (n - 3) << "! равно "
                << n * (n - 1) * (n -2) << ", мой Господин" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

В математике это кажется называется "размещения", в данном случае по 3.

Comment: Перестановки по 3

Comment: + условие if (n < 3) должно быть нестрогим, т.к. факториал для нуля определён и равен нулю

Comment: А что значит "несторогое условие n<3"? Если меньше, равно или больше?

Comment: alexlz, признаю свой грандиозный про**б. действительно пора перечитать учебник по математике. спасибо.

Comment: @shtelcner Ну уж так-то не надо. Все живы, никто не умер и даже не в больнице...

Comment: alexlz, само собою.) просто непривычно мне осознавать, что кто-то ткнул меня носом в нехилый недочёт в моих познаниях математики :D
проблема в том, что написанный вами код он-лайн система проверки, используемая в моём университете, засчитывает только на 90%.
мой код с использованием функций она не приняла вообще, хотя я вроде бы всё правильно написала - компилятор выдавал исключительно верные ответы, а этот - на 10% её не устраивает.
вообще не понимаю, что ей надо)

Comment: @shtelcner А каковы требования этой системы? Может ей не нравится нормальный ответ в случае N == 3?

Comment: Суть задачи: между N (N<100) командами проведён турнир. 
Сколькими способами могут быть распределены золотая, серебряная и бронзовая медали, если одно призовое место может занять только одна команда?
при N=3, ответ - 6. всё верно вроде как.

Comment: Может система предполагает, что считать надо:

1) в целых (видимо unsigned long long будет хорошим выбором)

2) в ходе вычислений нужна проверка переполнения.

Comment: @shtelcner Тады минимальное количество команд -- 2 (два варианта распределения мест).

@avp При N=100 результат 970200. В 4б signed int вполне влезает

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    long double fact,fact1;
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    for (int i = N - 1; i > 0; i--) 
        fact = fact * i;/*при решении (fact * i) переменная fact неинициализирована, тоесть в fact1 хранится мусор*/
    for (int i1 = N - 4; i1 > 0; i1--) 
        fact1 = fact1 * i1;/*при решении (fact1 * i1) переменная fact неинициализирована, тоесть в fact1 хранится мусор*/

    cout <<fact/fact1<<endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

то есть до первого использования переменных fact и fact1, им нужно придать определённое значение

```
long double fact=0.00,fact1=0.00;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, запомню.) Но появилась новая беда - что ей не вводи, выдаёт ответ: "-1#IND"

Comment: смотри ответ @alexlz , и вообще что ты хочешь получить от умножения "0" на i ??? а потом ещё деления 0 на 0???

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat Если мне не изменяет склероз, то для современных чисел с плавающей запятой (какой там стандарт IEEE?) должно получиться симпатичное значение NaN (not-a-number).

Comment: @alexlz я не понял к чему ты это... на мою запись не ругается...

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat я к тому, что деление 0 на 0 -- штука не такая уж и страшная. Вполне себе результат (а когда-то -- исключительная ситуация, прекращение программы...)